# Get Exchange Mailbox info using C# without Powershell

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010

I want to connect to an Exchange server and retrieve information about a user's mailbox **without** using powershell.

I've been searching for articles which could help me but I keep getting articles which in some way use powershell to retrieve these values. The reason why I don't want to use powershell is because I'm developing a tool which can help us automating tasks. Not everybody has powershell installed.

Can anybody give me some pointers which namespace/library I can use to connect to a mailbox or exchange server, to see which database is being used, how large it is etc.

I'm fairly good at programming in C# but I need the necessary namespaces to get the information.

I hope that somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the Exchange Web Services Managed API, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710.aspx

Comment: I've come across that library but doesn't have any functionality to get the database the mailbox resides on or on which server it is placed. At least I didn;'t find the solution

Comment: I don't use it to access that type of information, but some of what you need ought to be in there.  Did you look at the ManagedFolderInformation class,   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.managedfolderinformation_properties.aspx